# Excel Polynomial Regression with multiple variables

Tags: excel, regression

I saw a lot of tutorials online on how to use polynomial regression on Excel and multi-regression but none which explain how to deal with multiple variable AND multiple regression.

In  [image: this image], the left columns contain all my variables X1,X2,X3,X4 (say they are features of a car), and Y1 is the price of the car I am looking for.

I got about 5000 lines of data that I got from running a model with various values of X1,X2,X3,X4 and I am looking to make a regression so that I can get a best estimate of my model without having to run it (saving me valuable computing time).

So far I've managed to do multiple linear regression using the Data Analysis pack in Excel, just by using the X1,X2,X3,X4. I noticed however that the regression looks very messy and inaccurate in places, which is due to the fact that my variables X1,X2,X3,X4, affect my output Y1 non-linearly.

I had a look online and to add polynomials to the mix, tutorial suggest adding a X^2 column. But when I do that (see right part of the chart) my regression is much much worse than when I use linear fits.

I know that polynomials, can over-fit the data, but I though that using a quadratic form was safe since the regression would only have to return a coefficient of 0 to ignore any excess polynomial orders.

Any help would be very welcome,

For info I get an adujsted-R^2 of 0.91 for linear fits and 0.66 when I add a few X^2 columns.

So far this is the best regression I can get (black line is 1:1):

[image]

As you can see I would like to increase the fit for the bottom left part and top right parts of the curve.

Comment: It happens sometimes that when you have a target variale in the order of 100 and you add variables with an order of magnitude of 1E10 the R2 goes down as the algorithm has to work with such small numbers in the coefficients that the rounding effects start messing things up.

Comment: Thanks, but is adding columns of x^2 still the way to do it ?

Comment: I would not use X2^3, that's for sure. Since you only have 4 columns of data, you can do manually a technique which consists in adding every squared variable one by one and see which ones give you the best R2. You can get a bad case of overfitting, but mathematically speaking it works.

Comment: I edited my question with my best current outputs